# Crusader Kings 2 mod game of thrones not working

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I installed the game (through steam) version 1.06b on windows 7 x64. i downloaded the mod and extracted contents to mod folder. I open the game and check game of thrones and it crashes. I found on the internet that mac users were having similar problems and tried there solution of changes the .mod file

from

```
path = /mod/A Game of Thrones"
```

to

```
path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/crusader kings ii/mod/A Game of Thrones"
```

the game now loads but without the mod. Also the game loads fine if I dont select the mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have version 0.2 of the mod or higher.  I had the same problem until I found the latest version of the GoT mod.